# Use Google Cdn to server mirrored images frrom my own website

Tags: google-cdn

"" A mirroring CDN doesn’t require you to upload anything to get started.  Basically you point it at your server where all the content is located.  As requests are made to the CDN for your static content, it retrieves it from your servers and stores it on the CDN network for a specific amount of time before it looks for a fresh copy.  While stored on the CDN network it constantly serves from that cached copy, this reduces the bandwidth and strain on your server, because the CDN only requests the static file once until the CDN file has timed out.  The time out is typically an hour or a day, but can be longer based on your settings.""

http://nickberardi.com/setting-up-a-cloudfront-mirroring-cdn-in-5-minutes/

This is what amazon cloudfront can do.

I would like to use google-cdn to do the same, mirror my own website resources.

However i cannot find out how can and where can i introduce my own website url for google cdn to mirror it. There is a lot of talk to 'load-balancer' and i cannot figure out what role does that have if any.

I believe a lot of people have this problem since searching in google for details on this, results in nothing.

Comment: You cannot use Cloud CDN by itself; it's a feature you can add when you're setting up HTTP(S) load balancing.  HTTP(S) load balancing requires that you either host content using VM instances in GCP or in GCP storage buckets. If your website is hosted in another way, you cannot use Cloud CDN.

Comment: Some more information about HTTP(S) load balancing is available here[1] and another one here.[2]
Alternatively, if you're looking for a method to host certain parts of a website in Google Cloud, you can use Cloud Storage[3] to do so.

[1]:https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/
[2]:https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/content-based-example
[3]:https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website